# JavaFX8 DatePicker: Change the navigation menu

Tags: css, javafx, datepicker

I need to make a navigation menu similar to the navigation menu of the second "DatePicker".
Is there a quick solution in JavaFX 8?

[image]

Thanks

Comment: [This](https://github.com/sedj601/CalendarFx) is something I am currently playing with.

Answer (score 0):

I've released some JavaFX controls (work in progress) for the new Date & Time API (JSR-310) .

The library is Open Source. Maybe you find it useful as a starting point.

You can read more about it here:

http://puces-blog.blogspot.ch/2013/04/drombler-commons-javafx-controls-for.html

http://puces-blog.blogspot.ch/2013/12/drombler-commons-date-and-time-controls.html

Current Javadoc: http://www.drombler.org/drombler-commons/current/docs/site/drombler-commons-fx/drombler-commons-fx-time/apidocs/index.html

The library is available from Maven Central:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.drombler.commons</groupId>
    <artifactId>drombler-commons-fx-time</artifactId>
    <version>0.9</version>
</dependency>
```

You can find some sample code here: http://sourceforge.net/p/drombler/drombler-commons/ci/default/tree/drombler-commons-fx/drombler-commons-fx-samples/drombler-commons-fx-samples-time/